Filter a ListBox displaying in a Userform by a specific column in Excel
I created a UserForm that enters data into a sheet. The form enters the data in cells A2:O2 and down. In my entry data UserForm, there is a button that displays a ListBox with every record entered. I want to filter this records by a specific column. The condition is: show every record that has that specific column blank.
Sub UpdateListBox() 
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim listItem As String
   
    With frmOpenRecords.lstOpenRecords
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 15
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "60; 80; 60; 100; 180; 100; 100; 250; 250; 65; 70; 80; 105; 100, 50"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With
  
       For i = 2 To lastRow
            If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = "" Then
                frmOpenRecords.lstOpenRecords.RowSource = "Database!A2:N" & lastRow
            End If
        Next i
End Sub

The code above is what I have for now but it shows every record including the ones not blank in that specific column. Also, I have tried 3 different variations of code but none of them works. This is the only one that at least displays the ListBox. If somebody know how to fix this, please don’t hesitate to reply. Thankss!!

Please post the code, not a screenshot of your code, including any variations you are able to display.  Additionally, please provide more context for the filtering.

The column I want to filter by stores a date. The column is called “Actual repair date”. If there is an Actual Repair Date in any record, it means that the record status is closed, but if the Actual Repair Date is empty, it means the record is open. I want to filter the ListBox to only show open records

You can filter the records using AutoFilter, then copy the visible records to another [hidden] sheet, and set the RowSource to the copied records on that sheet.  You could also populate the listbox from an array but then you lose the column headers

Tim hit on what I was going to suggest:  Fill a listbox with an array & Addpend dynamic array.  The most economical version of this for me has been to capture the whole range in an array, then loop through the array in memory, not via the sheet, to populate your listboxArray.  That overall should speed up the process.

Can you help me with the code? Because I have no idea how to code the array

@JorgeOmarDavidGonzalez that is within the links provided in the above comment.

You can try the following code, which lists all the data in sheet Database where Column N is empty.
Note that, the column headers will not be displayed on the ListBox automatically, so you need to use Label controls on top of the ListBox to display the headers.
Sub UpdateListBox()
    Dim myFile As String, adoCN As Object, RS As Object, strSQL As String
    
    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    With frmOpenRecords.lstOpenRecords
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 15
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "60; 80; 60; 100; 180; 100; 100; 250; 250; 65; 70; 80; 105; 100, 50"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With

    Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    adoCN.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    adoCN.Properties("Data Source") = myFile
    adoCN.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=No; IMEX=1"
    adoCN.Open
    
    strSQL = "Select * From [Database$] Where F14 Is Null"
    
    RS.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    RS.Open strSQL, adoCN
    
    frmOpenRecords.lstOpenRecords.Column = RS.GetRows(RS.RecordCount)
End Sub


Thanks for taking the time to help me. I tried the code but it gives me an error on line “adoCN.Provider = “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0””

What does it say in the error message?

I tried it again and now it’s giving me this error message “Method ‘Open’ of object ‘_Connection’ failed” on line “adoCN.Open”

Is the Excel file on your PC or OneDrive ?

Is on my OneDrive

You need to use the local file path for the variable myfile . Do a search on the site...
